# How to get set selected value inside TextField of AutoComplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I have array of Object

```
const top100Films = [{ title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },{ title: 'The Godfather', year: 
1972 },{ title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },{ title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },{ 
title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 }]
```

I'm using Autocomplete of Material UI

```
<Autocomplete
                // value={val}
                options={top100Films}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)}
                renderInput={params => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label="label"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth

                    />
                )}
            />
```

It just displays the value inside TextField but doesnot actually sets the value like

```
<input
        type="text"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
      />
```

This input sets the value.

I want to set the value inside Autofield's TextField not just display it. How can it be done? I have searched but I couldn't find any solution.

If anyone needs any further information please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check its [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) where it is clearly mentioned:

> Signature: `function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void event: The event source of the callback. value: The new value of the component`.

here the first parameter is the `event` and `second` is the value.

So you can get the selected value like:

```
onChange={(event, selectedValue) => handleChange(selectedValue)}  // You can get the `selectedValue` inside your handler function on every time user select some new value
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that where you can set a state to another value and actually have the Autocomplete change it ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-hertz-zzc19?file=/src/App.js

[Material UI doc](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#ControllableStates.js)

Comment: Thank you for your response but actually I was looking for on how to set value on TextField not just render it but actually set it. Any how thank you. Cheers!! :)

Comment: Oh I see, indeed it's different from what I understood

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out... to set value to the TextField we can do is:

```
             <Autocomplete
                options={top100Films}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={params => (
                    <TextField
                        value={props.value}
                        onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
                        {...params}
                        label="label"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth

                    />
                )}
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.innerText)} //This in actual 
                                                                      sets the value
            />
```